# PlayonLinux League of Legends Crashes Updating

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

Hello so I am trying to install League on Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid... Right now League is on 6.10 update and I am trying to find a bug in this but I only find one simple bug in all of this... And I am making sure NOT to tick mark the thing... This is my Error... (The very last lines...)

```
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
fixme:gdi:GdiInitializeLanguagePack stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x2a1ea08 (nil)): stub
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from multi-threaded to apartment threaded
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x92fea08 (nil)): stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x121e024 (nil)): stub
fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33ef44 (nil)): stub
fixme:advapi:UnregisterTraceGuids deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
```

Whats confusing me is the deadbeef which a music player... And that error that doesn't seem all that... you know... Important... So plz tell me if this is an actual bug that I specifically have or something else... And BTW I tried the latest one with 1.9.9-staging... And got the same results...

Comment: deadbeef isn't a music player in this context. It is the address that could be assigned to a wrong pointer for ease of debugging and fun *(cause just for ease there's a null ptr)*. [So called hexspeak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak). You didn't say what exactly goes wrong with the install — is it hangs? Crashes? Or what? Looking at the part of log you posted [everything seems to be fine](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#I_get_lots_of_.22fixme:.22_messages_in_the_terminal_and_Wine_runs_a_bit_slow).

Comment: Let me reinstall League of Legends real quick! Sorry I haven't been on here for some time... I was working on this! https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2828-SuperFighters_Deluxe.html And some other stuff...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I must be blind, you wrote that it is a crash in the title ☺ Well, as you tried latest versions, and nothing changed, it seems you have [to report a bug](https://wiki.winehq.org/Bugs). Note — it's described by the link — that you have to test it on the latest usual wine build, not  the staging one.

Comment: OH I justed check the PlayonLinux LoL thing and that they are currently working on a fix with the new wine 1.9.11... I think you can close this topic!

Comment: Did you mean someone reported a bug? Then you probably want to answer your own question with explanation that the problem is known, and with the link where they're working on the fix.

Comment: Sorry I haven't had internet connection for a long time....

Comment: And I kind of gave up on it... Thanks though!